# Why did this Changeling become suicidal?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

In [DS9: Apocalypse Rising](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Rising_(episode)), the changeling who's

> taken the form of Martok

tries to kill Odo for identifying him. Between hundreds of angry Klingon fighters hunting for changelings he should have known that he will be killed in just moments.

If he had really wanted to kill Odo (not being capable to change form at the time), he could have done so easily, like this:

He could have done also this:

Instead, he tried to strangle him

Why didn't this changeling use a more effective method. Was it perhaps because "*no changeling has ever harmed another"*, but then why he didn't flee instead?

Comment: What does this have to do with suicide? It seems like you're asking 2 different questions.

Comment: @TheIronCheek He intentionally committed something what unavoidably leads to his imminent death. Making others to kill us can be considered suicide. [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_by_cop) for this terminology in a different context. But if you have a better idea, how to reformulate the question title, I am open for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's honestly not clear (looking at the [original screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/499.txt)) why the Martok/Shapeshifter decided to use *that particular method* to try to kill Odo, other than that it was surprised to be exposed so dramatically and felt that choking him ***seemed like a good idea at the time***.

It presumably thought that it would have more than a few seconds in which to kill him. Sisko was quick on the draw though.

> Odo tumbling into the room, wrestling with Martok.
>
> **ODO:** *Gowron's not the changeling. It's Martok.*
>
> Realizing he has been exposed, Martok sprouts tentacles of changeling
> goo from his side and wraps them around Odo, trying to strangle the
> life out of him.
>
> And as the tentacles tighten around Odo's neck...
>
> There's a flash of disruptor fire; Martok is blown away from Odo.
>
> 129  CLOSE ON SISKO (OPTICAL)
>
> Who still has his disruptor trained on Martok.
>
> 130  ANGLE MARTOK (OPTICAL)
>
> As he staggers to his feet, more and more of his body shape-shifting
> into goo. He starts back toward Odo.
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Apocalypse Rising](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/499.txt)</sup></sub>

Comment: So he wanted to break Odos neck quickly, and then escape. But Odo's neck didn't break, and the klingons, and Sisko, reacted too fast.

Comment: Isn't there a general tendency for *Star Trek* villains to do stupid things and/or randomly fly into a rage when they are exposed?  I didn't see this particular incident as all that atypical, TBH.

Comment: @Kevin Weyoun, Dukat, Wynn, Female Changeling. They were sometimes unlucky, but I can't remember any very big idiotism (particularly not one in such hardiness) what they've done.

Answer (score 4):

Simple... he panicked.

The Founders are slow methodical strategists who are devious beyond compare when they have time to plan.  When they have to improve on the fly... slightly less so.

In the heat of battle, Changeling-Martok got flummoxed and went with the first impulse that popped into his head.  Remember Changelings are not by nature a violent or warlike race. Hence why they needed to create a race of genetically-engineered sociopaths to do their killing for them